# Google Play Billing Library 3.0 Released. How to migrate from 2.2.0, any changes needed?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, play-billing-library

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes

I have implemented in app purchases (non consumable one time purchases only) using the version 2.2.0 billing library. Now the latest update has come which provides AIDL migration guide, but what about the devs already using the previous latest version.

Do we have to make any changes or the code will work as it is?
(Of course I'll just test it, but want to ensure I'm not missing anything)

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder about that too. A major release just sounds like a big change. But according to the release notes, simple in-app purchases should not require any changes. Without guarantee of course.

Comment: @L3n95 Agreed! Also I did test by updating to 3.0.0 as it is and it all looks fine. However, need to do thorough testing. If you learn something feel free to let us know!

Comment: After the upgrade I get some crash reports with IllegalArgumentException. Do you have that too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63992345/illegalargumentexception-after-upgrading-to-google-play-billing-library-3-0

Answer (score 2):

Generally, so far, the changes seem limited to the release notes:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#3-0

If you're not using any of the removed methods and take care of the warnings provided by nullability annotations, you should be fine.

Also, take into consideration the default policies are changing by 1st of November '20:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html

Basically, if you don't support account hold, account restore, these will be mandatory by then. Also subscription pause and re-subscribe will be by default turned ON, don't forget to turn them off if you don't want them, all these use-cases will need testing. Sorry for the linked solutions, but it's well documented.

You have it working with billing lib 2.2.0 , I suppose you didn't really integrate it via AIDL, did you? Then you shouldn't be looking-up for that migration.

Comment: If my app is absolutely free and don't use any in-app purchase features, should I also start integrating Google Play's billing system with my app ? Despite I absolutely don't care about that ? (seems becoming mandatory https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/06/new-features-to-acquire-and-retain-subscribers.html)